# Can I set a bindAttr class on only the element that was clicked?

Tags: ember.js

Ive got got this table that gets sorted with some action functions:

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span {{action 'sortNums'}} {{bindAttr class=":carrot :active :up isActive:active direction"}}></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span {{action 'sortNums'}} {{bindAttr class=":carrot isActive:active direction"}}></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Inside the controller I have the action functions, and I would like to set the direction class only on the element that was clicked, not the whole thing:

```
 sortNums: function(){
    if (this.get('direction') === 'up') {
      this.set('direction', 'down');
      this.set('sortAscending', true);
    } else {
      this.set('direction', 'up');
      this.set('sortAscending', false);
    }
  }
```

I don't really think this is possible, and I may have to use views to do this, but just wondering...

Also, if i were to use views, am I going to have to have a view for every single `<span>` in my table? (I have like 7)

I dunno if this is possible, but if i could just get the DOM node for the clicked element, i could just add the class with jQuery.

Comment: IMO it will not add so much overhead to use views, you can define `tagName` to be of type `span`, since the view is the only place where you get access to the `event` object where you can then reference to the element that received the click

Comment: Cool yeah, just figuring out that right now, thanks.

Comment: I'm with @intuitivepixel on this, but of you're binding a css class i think you should use `classNameBindings` in your `View` class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the DOM element you should intercept the click to the `action` in a `view` and then forwarding it to the function call to your controller. As for the `view` you don't need a view for every `span` just capture the click events on the view that wraps the table.

Something like this should work:

```
App.TableHeaderSortView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  click: function(event) {
    this.get('controller').send('sortNums', event)
  },
  classNameBindings: [':carrot :active :up isActive:active direction'],
  direction: '...'
  ...
});

App.TheControllerBackingTheViewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    sortNums: function(event) {
      // event available here
    }
  }
});

<thead>
<tr>
  <th>
    {{view App.TableHeaderSortView}}
  </th>
  ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: okay, I have a setup pretty much how you outlined, now my problem is that i need to remove a class from all the views (span elements) at once.

Comment: @Watson, do you do this depending on property change in your controller? if so a simple observer in the view watching that property could toggle a property in your view that is included in the classNameBindings, you know what I mean?

Comment: as of right now, im using the same view multiple times and just passing in a parameter, like {{view App.LocationDataTable type='btu'}} i dunno if that is a weird approach. i will look into this observer stuff. Thanks!